# Intellij Idea & SVN : How to add all new files on "Commit Directories"?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, svn, intellij-idea

When I edit files and press `Commit Directories` - they are added to commit list. But if I created some files - they are not in commit list. I should manually search all new files and click `Subversion > Add to VCS`. Can it be done in simplier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by "Add silently".

*File -> Settings -> Version control -> Confirmation -> When files are created*

Comment: Ok, but I also add files from other programs : for example `save as` at Photoshop to my project folder. This files avoid `Add silently` option.